# How to make parent div above child div without position absolute?

Tags: css

Im am trying to make my parent div be on top of its child div, basically I have 2 divs that is floated inside my parents div, the left side and right side div.

```
<div id="parent">
     <div class="leftbox">left</div>
     <div class="leftbox">right</div>
</div>
```

Both child divs have float:left and width:50% css. Parent div got:

```
#parent {
   overflow:hidden;
}
#parent:hover {
   background: red;
}
```

What I want to do here is to cover the whole parent div with the background when the hover state is on, but the thing is when I hover on the parent div, it doesnt affect the child div making the impression that it is on top of the parent div, so what I did is I added:

```
position:relative;
```

to the parents div, but it still doesnt work. Any idea how I can achieve this? thanks!

PS: I dont really want to hide the child div, basically I just want to have the parent div on top of the it. I made the code simple but it seems I confused some of you. Here is what I wanna do, make the child div below the parent so it can get covered by the parents div background, but as you can see on my js fiddle, the childs div is on top of the parents background:

http://jsfiddle.net/MarkTe/jq12pu3p/

Comment: Please clarify your question maybe attach the desire effect with an image ....

Comment: This reads like you want to hide the child elements when the parent is hovered? But, really, I'm fighting to even try to understand what you want as the question is currently written.

Comment: this sounds like a clearfix issue.

Comment: Try adding `#parent:hover div { background-color: red; }`

Comment: @DavidThomas not really hide it, I just want the parent div to be on top of it.

Comment: Do you mean on top - i.e. covering - or on top as in positioned above it?

Comment: @MarkTe - afraid Im now more confused...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"not really hide it, I just want the parent div to be on top of it"

The only reason I could think you might want this is if the parent div was partially transparent, so you could still see the children underneath... In which case you could put a third div which was the same height & width as the parent but position absolute...

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="leftbox">left</div>
  <div class="leftbox">right</div>
  <div class="cover"></div>
</div>
```

Then...

```
div.cover {
   position:absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   transition: all .3s;
}     

#parent:hover > div.cover, div.cover:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}

#parent { position: relative; } /* As well as your own code */
```

Comment: awesome. not really what I have in mind but this generate the same result! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I've updated to be more in line with what you want

Answer (score 0):

You cant actually layer a parent above its children, but you can mimic the effect by toggling the visibility of the children when hovering the parent, thusly:

```css
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#parent:hover {
  background: red;
}
#parent:hover > div{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="leftbox">left</div>
  <div class="leftbox">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest, but the question - and the OP's response, in the comments - left me bewildered as to what on earth he wanted.

Comment: @DavidThomas- posted before the comments...and yes...now Im super confused :S